# How to implement the logic for a word search game in Godot

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I am new to the GODOT engine and I am trying to create a word search game. I am not sure where to start with the game and UI logic and unfortunately, there are no examples or tutorials to help me get started. Any advice or resources I could use?

Comment: For Godot tutorials try [KidsCanCode's Godot Recipes](https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/) and [GDQuest Free Godot Tutorials](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/). Please don't let the fact that there are no tutorials for your particular game genre discourage you. Instead break it down to particular problems, and then ask how to do those things. Asking for resources or where to start is considered off topic. In fact, I voted to close the question. By the way there is a sister site dedicated to game development: [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Appreciated. Hadn't used SO in a while